# fade slide animation flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, dart-null-safety

I saw many webs when scroll down they have slide fade animations on their widgetI am wondering how they work! Any example with fade slide animation will be appreciated

New to flutter wondering how to do where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: FadeTransitionExample(),
    );
  }
}

class FadeTransitionExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _Fade();
}

class _Fade extends State<FadeTransitionExample> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController? animationController;
  Animation<double>? _animationValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),);
    _animationValue = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(animationController!);

    animationController!.addStatusListener((status){
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed){
        animationController!.reverse();
      }
      else if(status == AnimationStatus.dismissed){
        animationController!.forward();
      }
    });
    animationController!.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: _animationValue!,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: 150,
              height: 150,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```